# Manipulating numpy matrices..replacing a value

Tags: python, numpy

I've recently discovered numpy and its usefulness when it comes to matrices. There is one thing that still bothers me tho. How do I replace a specific value in a matrix with a desired one. I've tried>

```
matrix1 = np.zeros([10,10])
replacewith = 1
atposition = np.array(5,5)
matrix1[atposition] = replacewith
```

So what I'm trying to do is replace the middle 0 with 1. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
matrix1 = np.zeros([10,10])
replacewith = 1
atposition = (5,5)
matrix1[atposition] = replacewith
print matrix1
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you, so the point is this doesn't take 2d array as an argument? You must write it manually?

Comment: The index *can* be specified using a variable if it contains a tuple of the correct size. I've updated my answer to show this. As for using a 2D array for the argument, how would you want to address an element in a 2D array using a 2D array? To clarify one thing, the expression `np.array(5,5)` in your question creates a new array of 5*5 = 25 elements, not a 2 by 1 array with the values `(5, 5)`. For further reference see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html.